# Can Tivoli be managed with Powershell?

Tags: windows, powershell, tivoli

Has anyone written or run across a more Powershell-ish way to work with Tivoli than its traditional tools?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know anything about Tivoli.  I did find this:
http://www-01.ibm.com/software/tivoli/resource-center/security/code-access-mgr.jsp

So, what Tivoli product are you looking to manage?  Try to find information about .NET support or SDK documentation for the particular product you're interested in.

Comment: Thanks Marco. Specifically, we are using IBM Tivoli Storage Manager Version 5.4. I was asking this for a coworker and didn't have all of the information at the time. It is sounding like they are going to "get by" for the moment, but Powershell support would be very handy.